# 2 Equations with 2 Unknown

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

This is an example from the Maximum Volume with Partial Derivative. But I can't follow the step how the author got the critical point $(4/3, 0)$.

$$V_x(x,y) = (1/3)(24y - 12xy - 4y^2)= 0$$ 
$$V_y(x,y) = (1/3)(24x - 6x^2 - 8xy)= 0$$

The next step book did was factor out the $x$, and $y$.

$$V_x(x,y) = (y/3)(24 - 12x - 4y)= 0$$ 
$$V_y(x,y) = (x/3)(24 - 6x - 8y)= 0$$

What is the next step? I tried to multiply $V_x(x,y)$ by x and multiply $V_y(x,y)$,subtract each other, the result is $-x^2y + 4xy^2 = 0$. But it is not clear where do I go from the next step.

Comment: Set each partial derivative to zero...

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are the two partial derivatives of $V$ assumed to be equal to zero, in the calculation of Maximum Volume? How is the critical point defined?

Comment: @M.Wind I think the critical points are the solution that solve both $V_x$ and $V_y$ simultaneously to 0. And once we have the critical point, I use the Second Partial Derivative Test to confirm if the critical point is a max, min or saddle. $d = f_xx * f_xx - [f_xy]^2$

Comment: @George. Okay, in that case there are $4$ critical points: ($0,0$), ($0,6$), ($4,0$), ($4/3, 2$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the 1st equation, either 1) $y=0\;\;$ or $\;\;1^{\prime}) \;3x+y=6$.

From the 2nd equation, either 2) $x=0\;\;$ or $\;\;2^{\prime})\;3x+4y=12$.

Assuming that $x$ and $y$ can be equal to zero, pairing up these conditions gives the points

$(0,0),\; (4,0),\;(0,6),\;(\frac{4}{3},2)$